# Different behavior as object member or as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I've tried to create a template helper for member function pointers, the main idea is to be able to do things like this:

```
template <typename T, typename R> struct TStruct
{
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef R return_type;

    R Function(T &);
};

struct Struct
{
    int Function(const int &);
};

typedef TStruct<const int &, int> A;

FunctionPointer<A, A::return_type, A::value_type>::pointer p = &A::Function;
typedef FunctionPointer<Struct, int, const int &>::pointer FPointer;
```

While doing it I realized that declaring pointer without the helper is shorter (this isn't the question now ;) but it drived me to an error that I don't understand. Let's supose that we have two versions of the helper:

```
template <typename Type, typename Return, typename Parameter> struct Good
{
    typedef Return (Type::*pointer)(Parameter);
};

template <typename Type, typename Return, typename Parameter, Return (Type::*Pointer)(Parameter)> struct Bad
{
    typedef Parameter pointer;
};
```

The `Good` one defines the pointer to member function type into the struct body, and the `Bad` one defines it into the template parameters and then `typedef` it into the struct body.

Using the `Good` struct my test program compiles:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // No compilation errors
    Good<A, A::return_type, A::value_type>::pointer GoodTStructPtr = &A::Function;
    Good<Struct, int, const int &>::pointer GoodStructPtr = &Struct::Function;

    return 0;
}
```

But if the `Bad` struct is used, there is a compilation error:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const int&’
    // from expression of type ‘int (TStruct<const int&, int>::*)(const int&)’
    Bad<A, A::return_type, A::value_type, &A::Function>::pointer BadTStructPtr = &A::Function;

    // invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const int&’
    // from expression of type ‘int (Struct::*)(const int&)’
    Bad<Struct, int, const int &, &Struct::Function>::pointer BadStructPtr = &Struct::Function;

    return 0;
}
```

AFAIK, `Good::pointer` and `Bad::pointer` are both of the type `Return (Type::*)(Parameter)` so they must be able to point to `&A::Function` or `Struct::Function`, but I'm clearly wrong but I don't know why. It *seems* that there's a different behaviour while the type is declared into a templated object body and when it is declared as template parameter.

So the question is: **Why isn't working the `Bad::pointer` as function pointer to the `&A::Function` or `&Struct::Function`**?

Comment: erm... maybe I misread it, but should "Bad"s struct-body not be
    typedef Pointer pointer;
?

Comment: `typedef Parameter pointer` looks very wrong.

Comment: Oh my god! is only a typo error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean?

```
template <typename Type, 
          typename Return, 
          typename Parameter, 
          Return (Type::*Pointer)(Parameter)> struct Bad
{
    typedef Pointer pointer;
    //      ^^^^^^^ (not Parameter)
};
```

Comment: Yes, it is a typo error.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster: Error messages usually contain enough information to understand this. Once you know what the issue is, look again at the error message and try to understand what the compiler says.

Comment: you're totally right, but after a long day of hard work i'm pretty silly, and btw *debo mejorar mi comprensión del inglés* ;)